# LUKS + TPM2 + PIN

Tags: systemd, luks, disk-encryption, secure-boot, tpm

I am currently aware of two recent methods to bind a LUKS encrypted root partition to a TPM2: `systemd-cryptenroll` and `clevis`. Both of them seem to release the encryption key after successfully checking the PCRs the key was sealed against.

But I don't like the idea of the volume being decrypted without user interaction. I'd rather have a solution like it is offered by BitLocker for Windows: Either TPM and an additional PIN or a recovery key.

Even though I searched the web quite exhaustively I was not able to find any hints in this direction. Is anybody aware of a solution?

EDIT: There is a `--recovery-key` option for `systemd-cryptenroll`. I'm only concerned with the question how to get an additional PIN requirement when using the TPM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 2022-05-21 - systemd v251

Support for TPM2 + PIN has been merged in systemd-cryptenroll and is available as part of release v251.

> Changes in disk encryption:
>
> - systemd-cryptenroll can now control whether to require the user to
>   enter a PIN when using TPM-based unlocking of a volume via the new
>   --tpm2-with-pin= option.
>
>   Option tpm2-pin= can be used in /etc/crypttab.

[Source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/releases/tag/v251-rc1)

Comment: I recently tried it and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support for two-factor authentication when opening a LUKS device. However, there will probably be at some point in the future.

LUKS itself doesn’t have any notion of needing two “passwords” (passphrases, key files, TPM keys...) to access a given device; it only knows about key slots, and one of those is sufficient to unlock a device. Tools which add support for other authentication mechanisms than those supported by LUKS piggy-back on top of this, and since they provide the extra authentication, the best place to require a PIN of some sort would probably be there. The developers of both Clevis and systemd are aware that there is interest:

- [Unlocking a device via TPM2 + "Tang or Passphrase"](https://github.com/latchset/clevis/issues/163) is the relevant feature request for Clevis;
- the “Future” section of [Lennart Poettering’s post on systemd 248’s support for TPM2 etc.](http://0pointer.net/blog/unlocking-luks2-volumes-with-tpm2-fido2-pkcs11-security-hardware-on-systemd-248.html) mentions Windows’ PIN + TPM2 mechanism.